# How to index an unpickled list?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, pygame, pickle

I'm making a LAN multiplayer arena shooter using pygame and sockets and am having troubling transferring pickled object data from server to client. I have 2 objects, player and projectile (the bullets). I don't know how to send multiple objects at once, so i decided to put the 2 objects in a list and pickle them. But when unpickling, I can't index the list as I keep getting the 'EOFError: Ran out of input'

So I want to unpickle the list that I receive and separate out the 2 objects in that list. But python won't let me index the list after I unpickled them. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
#instantiating instances for Player and Projectile classes

players=[Player(450,400,"sprite1.png",1),Player(500,400,"sprite2.png",2)]
bullets=[Projectile(50,50,5,"right","projectile.png",0)]  

def threaded_client(conn, player):
    player_data=(players[player])
    bullet_data=(bullets[player])
    alldata=[player_data,bullet_data]    #putting the 2 objects in a list.
    conn.send(pickle.dumps(alldata))     #pickling list

    reply = ""
    while True:
    try:
        alldata = pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))
        players[player] = alldata[0]
...

self.client.connect(self.addr)
alldata=pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048)) #unpickling the list
return alldata[0]   #trying to return the first object
```

Comment: What does `self.client.recv(2048*3)` value for? have you printed it? does this socket program that reciving have `Player` class too?

Comment: It's the amount of bits (2048) that I'm sending and receiving from client to server. 'self.client.recv' is where the client accesses the data from the server when it's being sent. That's why I named the variable 'alldata' and stored all the data (Player and Projectile objects) in that variable.

Comment: Well i know what thats mean, i asked for what the balue you get from it

Comment: The value is a pickled list containing the Player and Projectile object

Comment: I've put the 2 objects in a list and pickled them, then sent them through the network. That's what I'm receiving from 'pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))'. I just want to know how to unpickle this and separate the objects back to how they were again, python won't let me unpickle and index them.

Comment: What is the value of `self.client.recv(2048)`, the acual value, what does it print for

Comment: It won't let me print the value because of the error, but the value that self.client.recv(2048) should be is [player_data,bullet_data], because that 's what I sent in the threaded_client subroutine and is what should be received

Answer (score 1):

You need to make arrangements to ensure that you have the entire object before you unpickle. You're doing a `conn.recv(XXX)` but that does *not* mean you actually received all XXX bytes. On success, it means you got somewhere between 1 and XXX bytes (inclusive). If it's a small buffer, you often get the entire thing in one chunk but you should never count on that.

Generally, you'll want to send the byte count in a fixed-size binary format (typically using the `struct` module), then after retrieving the byte count, keep receiving until you got all the expected bytes or you get an error (i.e. your peer disconnected).

Something like this on the sending side:

```
import struct

pickled_bytes = pickle.dumps(thing_youre_sending)
p_size = len(pickled_bytes)                # Size of pickled buffer
p_size_buf = struct.pack("!I", p_size)     # Packed binary size (4 byte field)
conn.sendall(p_size_buf)                   # Send length (Note sendall!)
conn.sendall(pickled_bytes)                # Send actual pickled object
```

On the receiving side, you'll do something like this:

```
import struct

...
def recv_all(conn, rlen):
    """ Function to receive all bytes """
    recvd = 0
    buf = b''
    while recvd < rlen:
        rbuf = conn.recv(rlen - recvd)
        if not rbuf:
            # Client disconnected. Handle error in whatever way makes sense
            raise ClientDisconnected()
        recvd += len(rbuf)
        buf += rbuf

...
p_size_buf = recv_all(conn, 4)                 # Receive entire binary length field
p_size = struct.unpack("!I", p_size_buf)[0]    # (Unpack returns an array)

pickled_bytes = recv_all(conn, p_size)         # Receive actual pickled object
thing_you_sent = pickle.loads(pickled_bytes)
```

Comment: Oh ok, I did not know how to use struct. I'll try it out and see what happens. Thank you for your time and help.